# How to open the chrome browser with gulp-open?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am using gulp-open with gulp in windows 7:

```
gulp.task('op', function(){
    var options = {
        uri: 'localhost:8080',
        app: 'chrome'
    };
    gulp.src(__filename)
        .pipe(open(options));
});
```

The index.html file opens with the app when I use app:'Firefox' but when I use the chrome option it opens an empty index.html? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the OS you need to refer to the chrome app differently in options:

```
'google-chrome' // Linux 

'chrome' // Windows 

'google chrome' or 'Google Chrome' // OSX
```

Refer to section **Options.app** in [the NPM documentation about *gulp-open*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-open).

Comment: I should have mentioned I use windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I only added **http://** to the uri and it worked for me.

```
gulp.task('op', function(){
    var options = {
        uri: 'http://localhost:8080',
        app: 'chrome'
    };
    gulp.src(__filename)
    .pipe(open(options));
});
```

Comment: what is __filename here ?

Comment: I believe that is just a reference to the absolute path to the url you want to open

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet of my code that solves the issue for me, you can use it to modify yours accordingly:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var liveServer = require('gulp-live-server');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('live-server', function(done){
    var server = new liveServer('server/main.js');
    server.start();
    done();
})

gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('live-server', function(done){
    browserSync.init(null,{
        proxy:"http://localhost:7777",
        port:9001,
        open: true
    })
    done();
}));
```